# MongoDB update an unknown (nested) part of a document

Tags: mongodb

Given a collection containing data like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "3b4f1d16-2706-4a92-bf0c-f4949b43953b",
    "someProperty": {
      "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
      "label": "Apple"
    },
    "someArray": [
      {
        "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
        "label": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "234234324........",
    "propLevel1": {
      "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
      "label": "Apple"
    },
    "propLevel1_2": {
      "propOnLevel2": {
        "deeper": {
          "andDepper": {
            "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
            "label": "Apple"
          }
        }
      },
      "array1OnLevel2": [
        {
          "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
          "label": "Apple"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Looking for a way to update any occurrence of:

```
{
      "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
      "label": "Apple"
}
```

with (based on _id, update label)

```
{
      "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
      "label": "Car"
}
```

So the final collection would look like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "3b4f1d16-2706-4a92-bf0c-f4949b43953b",
    "someProperty": {
      "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
      "label": "Car"
    },
    "someArray": [
      {
        "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
        "label": "Car"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "234234324........",
    "propLevel1": {
      "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
      "label": "Car"
    },
    "propLevel1_2": {
      "propOnLevel2": {
        "deeper": {
          "andDepper": {
            "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
            "label": "Car"
          }
        }
      },
      "array1OnLevel2": [
        {
          "_id": "2253baac-68b5-4bce-9f78-0829de3b597c",
          "label": "Car"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: might need $function with a recursive function

Comment: I don't think there is a generic way for recursing nested structure for dynamic depth level. Consider refactoring your schema to store the entries as individual documents and use `$graphLookup` to reconstruct your recursive structure.